Springboot 3.3 can't get Maxmind GeoLite2-Country.mmdb file from classpath and results to null
I'm using maxmind GeoLite2-Country.mmdb in springboot 3.3. This what I did:
I subscribed and got a maxmind free licence which I used to download the database with bellow command:

curl
"https://download.maxmind.com/app/geoip_download?edition_id=GeoLite2-Country&license_key=HERE-MY-LICENCE&suffix=mmdb"
-o GeoLite2-Country.mmdb

Then then I verified that the file is indeed in the classpath src/main/resources/maxmind/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb and I added this to my gradle.build :
implementation 'com.maxmind.geoip2:geoip2:2.15.0'

Then I configured application.properties as below :

maxmind.geoip2.database=classpath:maxmind/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
spring.geolite2.filter-databases=false
geoip2.database.path=/maxmind/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
geoip2.database=file:src/main/resources/maxmind/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
spring.geolocation.database-reader.file=classpath:maxmind/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb

Then I tried to get the file in below code:
@Value("classpath:maxmind/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb")
    private String dblocation;
 @Bean(name = "GeoIPCountry")
    public DatabaseReader databaseReader() throws IOException, GeoIp2Exception {
        System.out.println(dblocation);
        final File resource = new File(this.getClass()
            .getClassLoader()
            .getResource(dblocation)
            .getFile());
        return new DatabaseReader.Builder(resource).build();
    }

But I'm getting error:

Caused by: o.s.b.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate
[com.maxmind.geoip2.DatabaseReader]: Factory method 'databaseReader'
threw exception with message: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.getFile()"
because the return value of
"java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(String)" is null

I even tried to download the file from this github repo but the error message remains the same.
I will be very gratefull to anyone who can help me solve this issue.

Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.getFile() simply says that getResource(dblocation) didn't return anything, it may be that GeoLite2-Country.mmdb is not present in the build (the jar) or that the downloaded file is not correct or not readable. Have you checked whether the GeoLite2-Country.mmdb file is corrupted or not ?

Thanks for the comment. How can I check that the GeoLite2-Country.mmdb is not a corrupted file ? the only thing I checked is that the  GeoLite2-Country.mmdb in present in the build under build/.../resources/maxmind/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb.
